# How to get required Transaction Fee in creating and deploying Gnosis Safe using their SDK core?

Tags: web3js, gnosis-safe, safe-core-sdk

how do i get the transaction fee which is required for creating and deploying a SAFE using core SDK?

`await safeFactory.deploySafe({ safeAccountConfig })`

This piece of code is doing that for me, but I am not sure how do i calculate the transaction fees required, so that I can inform the user to have required balance in their EOA wallet.